# How to close requests.Session()?

Tags: python, session, https, get, python-requests

I am trying to close a `requests.Session()` but its not getting closed.

```
s = requests.Session()
s.verify = 'cert.pem'
res1 = s.get("https://<ip>:<port>/<route>")
s.close() #Not working
res2 = s.get("https://<ip>:<port>/<route>") # this is still working which means s.close() didn't work.
```

How do I close the session? `s.close()` is not throwing any error also which means it is a valid syntax but I am not understanding what exactly it is doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `requests`'s source code, `Session.close` only close all underlying `Adapter`. And further closing a `Adapter` is clearing underlying `PoolManager`. Then all the 
established connections inside this `PoolManager` will be closed. But `PoolManager` will create a fresh connection if there is no usable connection.

Critical code:

```
# requests.Session
def close(self):
    """Closes all adapters and as such the session"""
    for v in self.adapters.values():
        v.close()

# requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter
def close(self):
    """Disposes of any internal state.

    Currently, this closes the PoolManager and any active ProxyManager,
    which closes any pooled connections.
    """
    self.poolmanager.clear()
    for proxy in self.proxy_manager.values():
        proxy.clear()

# urllib3.poolmanager.PoolManager
def connection_from_pool_key(self, pool_key, request_context=None):
    """
    Get a :class:`ConnectionPool` based on the provided pool key.

    ``pool_key`` should be a namedtuple that only contains immutable
    objects. At a minimum it must have the ``scheme``, ``host``, and
    ``port`` fields.
    """
    with self.pools.lock:
        # If the scheme, host, or port doesn't match existing open
        # connections, open a new ConnectionPool.
        pool = self.pools.get(pool_key)
        if pool:
            return pool

        # Make a fresh ConnectionPool of the desired type
        scheme = request_context['scheme']
        host = request_context['host']
        port = request_context['port']
        pool = self._new_pool(scheme, host, port, request_context=request_context)
        self.pools[pool_key] = pool

    return pool
```

So if I understand its structure well, when you close a `Session`, you are almost the same as creating a new `Session` and assign it to old one. So you can still use it to send request.

Or if I misunderstand anything, welcome to correct me :D

Comment: But `PoolManager` will create a fresh connection if there is no usable connection --> When does this happen?

Comment: When you create a fresh `PoolManager`, it just hold an empty `pools`. Or when you `clear` a `PoolManager`, it will clear `pools`.