# good way of deleting requests session

Tags: python, python-requests

I need to delete a requests session (not deleting the object itself, just the session), but I can't find a good way of doing so. I need to do that to restart the session from the start because it causes a problem in the server response.

```
import requests

class Uploader():

    def __init__(self):
         self.session = requests.Session()

    def upload(self):
         ...
         return True
```

I'm sorry If I it's not clear enough
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can close the session and reinstate it, see the [source code](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/master/requests/sessions.py#L744)

```
class Uploader():

    def __init__(self):
         self.session = requests.Session()

    def upload(self):
         ...
         return True

    def close(self):
        self.session.close()
```

Where appropriate you can reinstate the session:

```
s = requests.Session()
```

Comment: I tried and it doesn't work, I think it actually deletes the session, so the problem may come from the request itself or from the server, I'll look it up

Comment: It does not delete the session but closes all adapters of the session

Comment: @samsoumsamsoum how about `with requests.Session() as session:`?

Comment: @ventaquil that might work but then the `Uploader` must be a Context Manager and implement the `__enter__` and `__exit__`  methods

Comment: for reference to OP's first comment here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49253627/1344855

Comment: @dh762 and ventaquil  it gives me this error for both "self.session.close()" and with "requests.Session() as session:" "http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response"